# Convert from string[] to string Android

Tags: android, listview

How can I convert from String[] to String only? So I can assign `orderan` to `items` and i can put it into my listview.

Here's my code.

```
MyClass class= new MyClass();

String orderan =class.getName();
String[] items = orderan; **the problem here

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you simply want this:

```
String orderan = class.getName();
String[] items = {orderan};
```

Or even:

```
String[] items = {class.getName()};
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter wants an array, but you're trying to assign the string orderan into the array items. Instead, make a new array, and add orderran into it. Something like:

```
String[] items = new String[1];
items[0] = orderan;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Array and add the string to it.

```
String[] items = new String[1];
items[0] = orderan;
```

you can do it in one line

```
String[] items = {orderan};
```